# How to properly plot UTC data in Highcharts if labels do not match x-axis?

Tags: highcharts, momentjs, utc, moment-timezone

I have a series of data points (UTC date and value) that I need to plot using Highcharts, which by default uses UTC. However, the data can be in different user timezones, so in this example I am setting it to New York. I noticed that even though the tooltip on each of my data points is correct, e.g. those for 10/26, some of them seem to be plotted in the section of the plot corresponding to 10/27. I expect all 9 data points for 10/26 to be plotted before the 10/17 mark. Does anyone see the issue in my code? I have created a JSFIFFLE to illustrate the issue clearly.

```
var timeZone = 'America/New_York';
var timeZoneOffsetValue = moment(values[0].data[0][0]).tz("America/New_York")._offset;
console.log(timeZoneOffsetValue);
Highcharts.chart('container', {
        yAxis: {
        gridLineWidth: 0.5,
      gridLineColor: '#D6D6D6',
      tickInterval: 5,
      dashStyle: 'LongDash',
      lineColor: '#D6D6D6'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime',
        dateTimeLabelFormats: {
          day: '%m/%d',
          week: '%d/%b',
          month: '%b/%y',
          year: '%Y'
        },
        title: {
          enabled: true,
          text: 'date'
        },
        gridLineWidth: 0,
        lineColor: '#D6D6D6',
        lineWidth: 0.5,
        startOnTick: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        scatter: {
          marker: {
            radius: 5,
            states: {
              hover: {
                enabled: true,
                lineColor: 'rgb(100,100,100)'
              }
            }
          },
          states: {
            hover: {
              marker: {
                enabled: false
              }
            }
          },
          tooltip: this.toolTip
        }
    },
    chart: {
        marginTop: 5,
        marginRight: 0,
        reflow: false,
        backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1)',
        style: {
          fontFamily: 'Open Sans'
        },
        type: 'scatter',
        spacingBottom: 0,
        spacingTop: 0,
        spacingLeft: 0,
        spacingRight: 0
    },
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            var time = new Highcharts.setOptions({
              global: {
                timezoneOffset: -timeZoneOffsetValue
              }
            }, this);

            var s = '<b>' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%m/%d %H:%M:%S', this.x) 
            + ' - ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(this.y, 2);
            return s;
        },
    },
    series: values
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/thehme/a47Lbnwr/25/

**Note:** in my actual code, I have noticed that sometimes when I first load the plot, most of the time the 3 data points are in the 10/27 slot, but if I reload the plot, then sometimes the data points move into the 10/16 date range. This is what makes this more confusing.

Comment: Firstly, You've got Highcharts.setOptions in the formatter function which is wrong. Define setOptions globally and set `timezoneOffset` appropriately, because data is badly plotted because of it.